# how to run cesium js application in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, cesiumjs

Hi i am new to java and cesium i want to create a application using cesium js but i don know how to deploy and how to run this application in eclipse IDE.
please give me steps to run this application

Comment: Have you read the [Getting Started guide](http://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/cesium-up-and-running/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cesium provides this information on github [here](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Documentation/Contributors/EclipseGuide/README.md). Please read and follow the documention.